# How to convert file of all video formats to file of all audio formats in Android

Tags: android, audio, video

I want to develop an android application which will convert file of all video formats to file of all audio formats . And the question - what is the best way to decode file of video formats to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean extract the audio track/stream from a video and save it separately, then ffmpeg will allow you do this.

There are a number of ways to use ffmpeg in Android - using a wrapper is the way I find most convenient as it will allow you use the standard command line syntax.

The following wrapper is a popular one for ffmpeg on Android:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

and this ffmpeg syntax will allow you extract audio from a video file (mp4 in this case):

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -vn -sn output.m4a

Using this with the above wrapper, leveraging the examples refereed to on their site, you would use the following code:

```js
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
try {

  //Set the ffmpeg syntax you want to execute
  cmd = "-i input.mp4 -c:a copy -vn -sn output.m4a";

  ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
  });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
}
```